# pegar o html de um $('a').index(this);

Tags: jquery

Um exemplo mais simples do que eu quero seria o seguinte:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.excluir').click(function(){
        var i = $('a').index(this);
        alert(i);
    });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class='excluir'>link 1</a>
<a href="#" class='excluir'>link 2</a>
<a href="#" class='excluir'>link 3</a>

<a href="#" class='cadastrar'>link 4</a>
<a href="#" class='cadastrar'>link 5</a>
<a href="#" class='cadastrar'>link6</a>
```

Com esse código eu tenho retornado apenas o elemento **`a`** que recebeu o click.

Agora como fazer para ler o `html()` dele?

Usando

```
i.html()
```

não deu. Nem

```
i.text()
```

Código oficial da pergunta:

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  $("a.excluiPlano").click(function() {

      if (confirm('Deseja Excluir este Plano?\nAtenção: Excluindo esse plano, todas as fotos serão excluidas!\nDeseja prosseguir?') ) {

        $.ajax({
            url: "../_requeridos/excluiPlano.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'planoid': $(this).attr('planoid')},
            beforeSend: function() {    

              $(this).html("<img src='../_img/_bannerImgs/spinner.gif' />")

            },
            success: function (retorno) {

                if (retorno == 1) {

                    alert('Excluido com sucesso');
                    location.reload();

                } else {

                    alert("Erro na exclusão");

                }

            },
            cache: false,
            /* REMOVIDAS PARA QUE O AJAX ENVIE VARIÁVEIS FORA DO FORM/
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
            */
        });

        return false;

      }

  })


});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve usar `html()`, mas não no `i` (que é o índice do elemento), e sim no próprio elemento que foi clicado (no caso, `this`):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.excluir').click(function(){
        var texto = $(this).html();
        alert(texto);
    });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript"   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class='excluir'>link 1</a>
<a href="#" class='excluir'>link 2</a>
<a href="#" class='excluir'>link 3</a>

<a href="#" class='cadastrar'>link 4</a>
<a href="#" class='cadastrar'>link 5</a>
<a href="#" class='cadastrar'>link6</a>
```

No caso, `$('a.excluir')` só executa o código para as tags `a` cuja classe é `excluir`. Você pode mudar o seletor de acordo com o que você precisar (`$('a')` executa para todos os links, por exemplo).

---

Só que no seu caso, você está chamando este código dentro de um evento do ajax, e creio que neste escopo o `this` não vai mais se referir ao elemento `a` e sim a algum objeto do ajax. Neste caso, é melhor você setar o `this` em alguma variável e usá-la dentro do `beforeSend`:

```
$("a.excluiPlano").click(function() {
    var link = this;
    $.ajax({
    // ...
        beforeSend: function() {    
          // não usar "this" aqui, pois ele provavelmente vai se referir a algum objeto do ajax
          $(link).html("<img src='../_img/_bannerImgs/spinner.gif' />")
        },
```

Comment: E o `index` tb segue a mesma lógica: `var i = $(this).index()`

Comment: entendi. Mas e se no caso esses elementos a, tiverem em comum a mesma classe? Pois existem outros links na página com outras características

Comment: POR FAVOR, me desculpe, fui alterar a minha postagem e acabei alterando a tua por engano. Desconsidere a alteração.

Comment: `html()` pega tudo que está entre `<a>` e `</a>`. Se você quer filtrar por classe e outras características, pode mudar o seletor `$()` de acordo com o que você precisa. Mas do jeito que foi feito, `$('a').click` chama este código para todos os links que forem clicados, e `this` vai se referir ao link que foi clicado, independente da classe, atributos, etc

Comment: @CarlosRocha Atualizei a resposta

Comment: Só mais uma coisa: No caso clico no Link 3 e gostaria de trocar esse texto para Link 3125. Como fazer? No caso, o que eu tenho é uma imagem. Imagino que o processo deva ser o mesmo.

Comment: fiz da forma abaixo mas não funcionou $(this).html("<img src='../_img/_bannerImgs/spinner.gif' />")

Comment: Basta chamar `html` com o texto que vc quer colocar. Ex: `$(this).html("Link 3125")`. Na documentação tem mais exemplos: http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: fiz isso mas não funcionou. Vou colocar o código completo no final da pergunta. Dá uma olhada fazendo favor!

Comment: @CarlosRocha deveria funcionar, talvez o problema seja o caminho da imagem ou algum outro detalhe da página

Comment: Já observei isso. A outra imagem nem sai de cena. O problema não é o caminho

Comment: Talvez seja algum detalhe na função `ajax`. De qualquer forma, se vc quer mostrar uma imagem enquanto o ajax é processado, talvez esta abordagem seja melhor do que mudar a imagem do link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4684771

Comment: estranho que se eu fiazer: $("a.excluiPlano").html as imagns de todos os a.classm mudam mas como $(this).html não muda

Comment: o $(this) não está entrando no ajax

Comment: Eu sugiro debugar, colocar uns alerts, etc, para ver se aquela linha é chamada. Mas eu acho que é porque a função está sendo chamada dentro do evento `beforeSend`, e o `this` não se refere mais ao elemento `a` (e sim a algum objeto do ajax). E se vc colocar logo no começo (antes do `if(confirm`) algo como `var link = this` e usar a variável `link` dentro do `beforeSend`?

Comment: @CarlosRocha Atualizei a resposta

Comment: exatamente isso que ocorre. Dentro do before acho que o this seria o Ajax.

Comment: pensei em ir subindo de nível como $(this).closest($(this)).html(). Mas não funciona também não. Mas, enfim, isso ajuda a resolver o problema

Comment: desta forma a figura só está trocando após a rsposta do ajax. Acredita?

Comment: Acredito :) sempre que vou mexer com ajax, perco mais tempo com essas coisas de mudar imagem e outras "firulas" do que fazendo a lógica em si. Que bom que vc conseguiu resolver!